# After clipping raster in ArcMap, file appears black in any other applications?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, raster-dataset

I have a tiff raster dataset, using arcgis I clip the data (to a feature class perimeter), the clipped file displays fine within Arcgis. However, if I try to view the clipped image in any external application the whole file appears completely black.

I have opened the clipped image in photoshop, gimp, windows viewer and paint and it always appears completely black.

I managed to get the image to appear by declaring the value of 255 (white) as the transparent colour, but now all the white detail has become transparent.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.

Comment: Are you using pyramids?

Comment: These software packages may have issues dealing with floating point data.

Comment: Hi BritishSteel, no I am not using pyramids.

Comment: Hi Aaron, the data should not be floating point as it should only have values between 0 and 255.

Comment: How does it look in QGIS? If you want to see it in an external viewer use something like Data::Export Data in ArcMap then select 'use renderer' for 8 bit output.

Comment: Hi Michael, I do not have access to QGIS. When I export the data as you describe it appears fine but the image is is not clipped as needed

Comment: Consider performing the Data::export data on your already clipped (float) raster, it's that or clip the export with the same parameters. You can set masks and extents in the data frame, also in the Data::export dialog you can select either whole extent, view extent or as specified (clip to rectangle). There's two good options.

Comment: @Micheal Miles-Stimson, If I do that then the area that has been clipped will appear as white and I need it to either appear as transparent, but ideally as nodata. I am aware of using the clip to dataframe rectangle as you mentioned but I eventually need to automate the process of (using python) and that functionality is not available within arcpy. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It could be caused by bit depth. Try to convert your raster to 8 bit raster with Copy Raster Tool (https://geozoneblog.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/esri_workaround/).